# Is there any IDE that can give contextual help when working with classes that use opDispatch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, com, activex, d

I host a large VB6 project, and I consider migration to D.

For a large part, the project uses ActiveX automation objects (it mostly interacts with several MS Office applications). I know, that I can program COM reflection in D with the `opDispatch` that is very much like statically typed, yet I doubt that without any extra effort the IDE (Visual Studio) would recognize such idiom and offer contextual help (like automatic method completion, or parameter names hints) for imported COM objects.

Of course, I can always make custom interface for each COM class I use, but this would be a lot of typing, and would add a layer of complexity.

Comment: unless I'm mistaken you can iterate over all classes and create the com interface file with a tool

Comment: @ratchet No, I want it the other way: to import com objects into D with support of native IDE goodies, like automatic method completion and stuff.

Comment: if you use/create a tool to create those interfaces then you can use code completion

Comment: @ratchet Of course. Do you imply, that such tool is not (yet) available?

Comment: I have no idea ;). but it doesn't seem that much work to create such a tool

Comment: The current VS2012 C# integration of the `dynamic` keyword doesn't have true completion either, only for members which were previously accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a simple answer - no, there is no such IDE (yet). It would be a great addition to Mono-D or VisualD, so I suggest you file a feature request on their forum(s) and hope someone will work on it...

Comment: By "accepting" I accept your answer, not the state of the affairs ;-)... I hope, that one day I will be able to reverse the acceptance.

Comment: I certainly hope the same! :)